# How can i upload multiple images with description at same time using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am uploading multiple images using ajax that works fine, but now i want to pass description with images in array. Please help me to do this. Below is my code for image uploading.

```
const _that = $(this);
_that.attr('disabled', true);
var form_data = new FormData();
var totalfiles = document.getElementById('files').files.length;
for (var index = 0; index < totalfiles; index++) {
  form_data.append("files[]", document.getElementById('files').files[index]);
}
$.ajax({
  url: '<?php echo base_url('
  product_services / add ') ?>',
  type: 'post',
  data: form_data,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function(response) {
    for (var index = 0; index < response.length; index++) {
      var src = response[index];
      // Add img element in 
      <
      div id = 'preview' >
        $('#preview').append('<img src="' + src + '" width="200px;" height="200px">');
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML form**

```
<div class="images row">
   <div class="col-sm-12 dynamic_form" style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="desc">Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="description[]" id="desc" placeholder="Description" class="form-control">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Image</label>
            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" class="form-control">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <button type="button" class="add_more btn btn-primary">+</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Form Output**

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Just append the contents of the inputs to your FormData; their `.value` String, to be specific.

Comment: @ChrisG let me try

Comment: @ChrisG not working

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

You can use formdata like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
document.getElementsByName('file[]').forEach(inputField => {
    Array.from(inputField).prop('files')).forEach(file => {
        formData.append(file.name, file);
    });
});
```

PS: the "document.getElementById('files')" gets only 1 element, the id is singular, you can't set 2 elements with the same id, lemme know if u need something else!

Comment: Oh wait a sec, i made a mistake

Comment: Edited, like this should work dynamically, let me know if this solution works